# Provider media type matching?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

Any ideas how are @Provider Produces/Consumes types are matched?

I have a Provider that both Produces and Consumes Lua,  I'd also like to be able to Consume XML or JSON with the built-in Providers and reply with Lua from my Provider.

I can't seem to come-up with the right combination of Produces/Consumes values in my Lua Provider to make this happen but it seems like it should be possible.

Help?

Comment: My best guess at this point is the \@Produces and \@Consumes need to be in separate classes, but before I go to that trouble I'd like to be fairly certain that will work.

Comment: Ignore this. I was passed JAXBElements when I wasn't expecting them... found it and fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application input error, we've found and fixed it.